# How can I compare one columns data with two columns data in python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compare one column in a dataframe `data1` with two columns in another dataframe `data2`:
Column `Name` from `data1` with column `Name1` and `Name2` from `data2`.

`data1`:

```py
data1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Name': ['Cody', 'Billy', 'Jeniffer', 'Franc', 'Mark', 'Tamis', 'Danye', 'Leesa', 'Hector', 'Coy'],
     'Area': ['California', 'Connecticut', 'Indiana', 'Georgia', 'Illinois', 'Connecticut', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Illinois', 'California']}
)
```

`data2`:

```py
data2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Name1': ['Billy' , 'Cody', 'Coy', 'Danye', 'Franc', 'Alish', 'Rob', 'Bob', 'Cidi', 'Codi', 'Yiki', 'Hana'],
     'Points1': ['21', '27.5', '25', '21', '21', '19', '40', '30', '20', '50', '40', '54'],
     'Name2': ['Harry', 'Thomas' , 'Eric', 'Lucy', 'Jeni', 'Hector', 'Jeniffer', 'Leesa', 'Mark', 'Tamis', 'Mona', 'Jerry'],
     'Points2': ['20', '15.6', '24', '21', '19', '40', '30', '20', '50', '90', '80', '85']}
)
```

Output:

```
Name    Area       Points
Cody    California  27.5
Billy   Connecticut 21
Jeniffer Indiana    30
Franc   Georgia     21
Mark    Illinois    50
Tamis   Connecticut 90
Danye   Illinois    21
Leesa   Indiana     20
Hector  Illinois    40
Coy     California  25
```

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvHgW.png)

Comment: I think it would be easier and more useful to modify "data2" so that it contains only two columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this format

```
data = data2.loc[:,'Name1':'Points1']
data.columns = ["Name","Points"]
da = data2.loc[:,'Name2':'Points2']
da.columns = ["Name","Points"]
df = (data,da) 
Data = pd.concat(df)
out = pd.DataFrame.merge(data1,Data,on='Name')
```